# how to write to subprocess stdin using c# in ubuntu?

Tags: c#, ubuntu

i'm absolutely bad in making software especially c#, but one time i needed some small one. I had to include executing some terminal commands and i faced with `sudo` problem.

```
proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process ();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c \" " + "sudo service apache2 restart" + " \"";
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.Start ();
```

As u know after command sudo i've to type my password but i want to do it automatically. Maybe i can write it after or smth i don't know.
Or i can restrict that command using sudo idunno. PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: What exactly is the question, because you seem to have no idea what you actually want...?

Comment: i want to execute the command sudo service apache2 restart, but it doesn't work. obviously because the password is required, but i can't type my password the same as the c# programm works.

Answer (score 0):

install dotnet core in ubuntu in windows 
check official documentation
[Dot net core installation](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxredhat)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the following example: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/46c91711-755f-48fa-a4a8-92956082218f/howto-launch-process-and-write-to-its-stdin?forum=netfxbcl
It has been written for Windows, but it's exactly the same behavior you want to obtain.